# ggridges color gradient per group

Tags: r, ggplot2, ridgeline-plot, ggridges

I am trying to make a ridgeline plot with two groups and a color gradient within each group. So from dark blue to light blue for the Unionists and dark red to light red for the Indy group, for example.

Thanks in advance!

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
Catalan_elections %>%
  mutate(YearFct = fct_rev(as.factor(Year))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = YearFct)) +
  geom_density_ridges(
    aes(x = Percent, fill = paste(YearFct, Option)), 
    alpha = .8, color = "white", from = 0, to = 100
  ) +
  labs(
    x = "Vote (%)",
    y = "Election Year",
    title = "Indy vs Unionist vote in Catalan elections",
    subtitle = "Analysis unit: municipalities (n = 949)",
    caption = "Marc Belzunces (@marcbeldata) | Source: Idescat"
  ) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0.01, 0)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0.01, 0)) +
  scale_fill_cyclical(
    breaks = c("1980 Indy", "1980 Unionist"),
    labels = c(`1980 Indy` = "Indy", `1980 Unionist` = "Unionist"),
    values = c("#ff0000", "#0000ff", "#ff8080", "#8080ff"),
    name = "Option", guide = "legend"
  ) +
  theme_ridges(grid = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have the `Catalan_elections` data, so I'll try to provide a minimal example with dummy data.

For mapping multiple `fill` variables to different scales, you could use the `ggnewscale` package. A trade-off would be that you'd have to call seperate `geom_density_ridges_gradient` for each mapping.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'ggridges'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ggplot2':
#> 
#>     scale_discrete_manual
library(ggnewscale)

df <- data.frame(
  x = c(rnorm(100, -2), rnorm(100, 2)),
  y = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 100)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_density_ridges_gradient(data = df[df$y == "A", ],
                               aes(fill = stat(x)), scale = 1) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "lightblue", high = "darkblue",
                      name = "A") +
  # Note that a fill scale must exist already before a new one can be used
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_density_ridges_gradient(data = df[df$y == "B", ],
                               aes(fill = stat(x)), scale = 1) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "lightcoral", high = "darkred",
                      name = "B")
#> Picking joint bandwidth of 0.324
#> Picking joint bandwidth of 0.343
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-12-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I'm sure it would not be too difficult to extend this example to your own data.